# Alter profile picture using <img> tag and PHP

Tags: php, image, profile-picture

I'm still new on php. I'm currently building a website which a user can upload an image to change their profile picture.

The file of image will we insert into table `user`, row image location on database and directory "upload". The formatting is like `abc.jpeg`

My code for the `<img>` tag, which is where I display the profile image. But the image does not appear. Only the thumbnail image is displayed and not the exact image.

```
<img src=<?php 
    $current = $fgmembersite->UserEmail();
    if ($handle = opendir('upload/')) {
        $sql = "SELECT image_location FROM user WHERE email='$current'";
        //$file = mysql_real_escape_string($sql);
        if ((file_exists('upload/'.$sql) == $sql)) {
            echo 'upload/'.$sql.'.png';
        } else if (file_exists('upload/'.$sql)) {
            echo 'upload/'.$sql.'.jpg';
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
?> alt="">
```

If you don't mind, can you check my code and see where I went wrong? Thank you for your helping.

Comment: did you get the result correctly from the sql query?

Comment: @laiju yes. I have check my sql query and it doesn't show any error.

Comment: i don't see the code where you execute the sql query. Please add the code to execute your sql query https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: While @laiju is correct in pointing out an issue with your SQL, please use the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of the w3school one.

Comment: @laiju Thankyou for your helping. Now I can change my profile picture,